# Sum involving binomial coefficients and falling factorials

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to find a simplified form for this summation:

$$B(k,j) \equiv \sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{k+i} {i \choose j} (k-1)_{i-1} \quad \quad \quad \text{for } 1 \leqslant j \leqslant k,$$

where the terms $(k-1)_{i-1} = (k-1) \cdots (k-i+1)$ are [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) (and $(k-1)_0 = 1$ by convention).  I have done some work on this by generating a matrix of values of this quantity (see below) and I can recognise simplified forms for some of the parts of the matrix, but I have been unable to see a simplified form for the whole thing.

---

**Computing the terms and looking for a pattern:** In case it helps to try to recognise a pattern, I have computed a matrix of terms using the `R` code below.  From the matrix of values it is clear that $B(k,k) = (k-1)!$ and $B(k,k-1) = (k-1) (k-1)!$.  I also recognise that $B(k,1)$ is [A000255](https://oeis.org/A000255).  I do not recognise the overall matrix of numbers as any simple form.

```
#Generate function
B <- function(k,j) { T1 <- (-1)^(k+1:k);
                     T2 <- choose(1:k, j);
                     TT <- c(1,(k-1):1);
                     T3 <- cumprod(TT);

                     sum(T1*T2*T3); }

#Create matrix of terms
M <- 10;
BBB <- matrix(0, nrow = M, ncol = M);
for (k in 1:M) {
for (j in 1:k) { BBB[k,j] <- B(k,j); }}

BBB;  #k is the row, j is the column

         [,1]    [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]    [,9]  [,10]
 [1,]       1       0        0        0        0        0        0        0       0      0
 [2,]       1       1        0        0        0        0        0        0       0      0
 [3,]       3       4        2        0        0        0        0        0       0      0
 [4,]      11      21       18        6        0        0        0        0       0      0
 [5,]      53     128      156       96       24        0        0        0       0      0
 [6,]     309     905     1420     1260      600      120        0        0       0      0
 [7,]    2119    7284    13950    16080    11160     4320      720        0       0      0
 [8,]   16687   65821   148638   210210   190680   108360    35280     5040       0      0
 [9,]  148329  660064  1715672  2870784  3207120  2392320  1149120   322560   40320      0
[10,] 1468457 7275537 21381624 41278104 54701136 50394960 31872960 13245120 3265920 362880
```

Comment: $B(k,j)=(k-1)(B(k-1,j)+B(k-1,j-1))$

Comment: $B(k,k-n)=(k-1)!P_{n}(k)/n!, [k^0]P_{n}(k)=(-1)^na(n), \sum\limits_{m=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-m}[k^m]P_{n}(k)=b(n)$ where $a(n)$ A000262, $b(n)$ A002720.

Comment: $B(k,1)=\lfloor{(k+1)(k-1)!+1\over e}\rfloor, B(k,2)=\lfloor{(k^2+k-1)(k-1)!+1\over 2e}\rfloor$

Comment: Also $B(k,3)=\lfloor{(k^3-4k+1)(k-1)!+1\over 3!e}\rfloor, B(k,4)=\lfloor{(k^4-2k^3-7k^2+12k+1)(k-1)!+2\over 4!e}\rfloor$ and so on, but it looks like this polynomial is more tricky.

Answer (score 2):

**Some Asymptotic Approximations**

The AM-GM inequality says
$$
\frac{k!}{(k-i)!}\le\left(k-\frac{i-1}{2}\right)^i\tag1
$$
The fact that
$$
\frac{k(k-i+1)}{\left(k-\frac{i-1}2\right)^2}=1-\left(\frac{\frac{i-1}2}{k-\frac{i-1}2}\right)^2\tag2
$$
allows us to derive
$$
\frac{k!}{(k-i)!}\ge\left[1-\frac{\frac13\left(\frac{i+1}2\right)^3}{\left(k-\frac{i-1}2\right)^2}\right]\left(k-\frac{i-1}{2}\right)^i\tag3
$$
and therefore,
$$
\frac{k!}{(k-i)!}\sim\left(k-\frac{i-1}{2}\right)^i\tag4
$$
from which, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\binom{k-j}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}
&\sim\left(\frac{k-j-\frac{i-1}2}{k-\frac{i-1}2}\right)^i\\
&\sim\left(\frac{k-j}{k}\right)^i\left(1-\frac{i(i-1)j}{2k(k-j)}\right)\\[6pt]
&=\left(\frac{k-j}{k}\right)^i-i(i-1)\left(\frac{k-j}{k}\right)^{i-2}\frac{j(k-j)}{2k^3}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
and therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\frac{\binom{k-j}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}
&\sim\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\left[\left(\frac{k-j}{k}\right)^i-i(i-1)\left(\frac{k-j}{k}\right)^{i-2}\frac{j(k-j)}{2k^3}\right]\\
&=e^{-\frac{k-j}k}\left(1-\frac{j(k-j)}{2k^3}\right)\\[3pt]
&\sim e^{-\frac{k-j}k-\frac{j(k-j)}{2k^3}}\tag6
\end{align}
$$

---

**Approximation of the Sum**

We don't get an exact closed form, but here is a pretty good asymptotic approximation:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{k+i}\binom{i}{j}(k-1)_{i-1}
&=\frac1k\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{k-i}\binom{i}{j}(k)_i\\
&=\frac1k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(-1)^i\binom{k-i}{j}(k)_{k-i}\\
&=(k-1)!\binom{k}{j}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\frac{\binom{k-j}{i}}{\binom{k}{i}}\\
&\sim\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{(k-1)!\binom{k}{j}e^{-\frac{k-j}k-\frac{j(k-j)}{2k^3}}}\tag7
\end{align}
$$
This is good when $k$ is large, exact when $j=k$, and extremely close when $j=0$. In fact, it looks as if the ratio of the approximation to the actual sum is asymptotically $1+\frac{(4j+k)j(k-j)}{6k^5}$. The maximum of this ratio is when $\frac jk=\frac{3+\sqrt{21}}{12}\approx0.63188$, where $\frac{(4j+k)j(k-j)}{6k^5}=\frac{27+7\sqrt{21}}{432k^2}\approx\frac{0.13675}{k^2}$ .

For example, when $k=10$ and $j=5$, $(7)$ gives $54775664.104$, which is about $0.136\%$ above the value in the table in the question.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{k+i}\binom{i}{j}(k-1)_{i-1}
=
\frac{\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(1+j)}(-1)^k \sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i}\frac{\Gamma(i+1)}{\Gamma(i-j+1)\Gamma(k-i+1)}
\end{equation}
substitute $i'=k-i$ and use $(.)_n$ for the risign factorial (Pochhammer's symbol)
\begin{equation}
=
\frac{\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(1+j)}(-1)^k \sum_{i'=k-1}^0 (-1)^{k-i'}\frac{\Gamma(k-i'+1)}{\Gamma(k-i'-j+1)\Gamma(i'+1)}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=
\frac{\Gamma(k)}{\Gamma(1+j)} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{\Gamma(k+1)(j-k)_i}{(-k)_i\Gamma(k-j+1)\Gamma(i+1)}(-1)^i
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=
\frac{\Gamma(k)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(1+j)\Gamma(k-j+1)}
% \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}
% \frac{(j-k)_i}{(-k)_i\Gamma(i+1)}(-1)^i
{}_1F_1(j-k;-k;-1)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=
\Gamma(k)
\binom{k}{j}
{}_1F_1(j-k;-k;-1)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=
\Gamma(k)
\binom{k}{j}
\sum_{i=0}^{k-j} \frac{(j-k)_i}{(-k)_i}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=
\Gamma(k)
\binom{k}{j}
\sum_{i=0}^{k-j} \frac{(j-k)(j-k+1)\cdots (j-k+i-1)}{(-k)(-k+1)\cdots (-k+i-1)}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=
\Gamma(k)
\binom{k}{j}
\sum_{i=0}^{k-j} \frac{(k-j)(k-j-1)\cdots (k-j-i+1)}{(k)(k-1)\cdots (k-i+1)}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=
\Gamma(k)
\frac{k!}{(k-j)!j!}
\sum_{i=0}^{k-j} \frac{(k-j)!(k-i)!}{(k-j-i)!k!}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=
\Gamma(k)
\frac{1}{j!}
\sum_{i=0}^{k-j} \frac{(k-i)!}{(k-j-i)!}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=(k-1)!
\sum_{i=0}^{k-j} \binom{k-i}{j}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}
\end{equation}